# Autocad .NET - expand command line

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm developing an Autocad .NET plugin (`.dll` loaded via `NETLOAD`), and I'm using a lot the `Document.Editor` object to get user inputs, like strings, numbers, points and entities.

I want some of my prompts to show several options for the user to select (exactly as it happens with the native `-DWGUNITS` command).

Displaying the prompt and the options is pretty ok (I'm doing it with an `Editor.GetInteger`, passing a multiline message with the options, and sometimes one or two keywords).

But I cannot figure out how to **expand the command bar** to make it show all the options (otherwise the user must manually expand it to see the list)

**So, here is my command currently (private content in blue):**

The options are limited to these three lines (changing `CLIPROMPTLINES` doesn't seem the best option, but if you know how to do it with `.NET`, it's a good start).
[image: This image represents my command]

.

**And here is what I want:**

[image: This image shows the intended behavior]

Comment: Have you tried asking this question at Autodesk forum? Full time Autodesk employees do answer questions there from time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple and this option is in `Autodesk.Autocad.ApplicationServices.Application.DisplayTextScreen`:

```
using Autodesk.Autocad.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;

private int AskUser(IEnumerable<string> userOptions)
{

        Document document= Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Editor editor = document.Editor;

        //Autocad's setting before you change
        bool originalSetting = CadApp.DisplayTextScreen;

        string message = "Available options:\n";
        message += string.join("\n",
            userOptions.Select((opt,i)=>i.ToString() + ": " + opt));
        message += "\nChoose an option"

        PromptIntegerOptions promptOptions = new PromptIntegerOptions(message);
        promptOptions.LowerLimit = 0;
        promptOptions.UpperLimit = userOptions.Count - 1;

        //display full command bar
        Application.DisplayTextScreen = true;
        var result = editor.GetInteger(promptOptions);

        int selection;
        if (result.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
            selection = result.Value;
        else
            selection = -1;

        //restore original setting
        Application.DisplayTextScreen = originalSetting;

        return selection;
}
```